# DropDownList Enter Event Issue

Tags: css, asp.net

When I focus on my DropDownList in UI, it opens and shows data. If I try to Select the text from DropDownList by hitting enter key, then it should select a text and move to another input control. But, this is not happening in my case.

Tab Selection and mouse Selection are working. It happening at limited places in my page And Project.

I tried solution by removing CSS. I Tried googling too. But, I didn't get the actual cause of issue and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your control is posting back with selectedIndexchange event then next focus element  will not be  focused because postback happened.

To do that you have to find next element and make focus on that change event like below

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" OnTextChanged="txtFirstName_TextChanged" placeholder="" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


  <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" OnTextChanged="txtFirstName_TextChanged" placeholder="" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
  protected void txtMEMBID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if(ValidCondition)
    {
      //go to next element
      txtLastName.Focus();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, when I press ENTER the SelectedIndexChanged event is invoked

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">   
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem>Primo</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Secondo</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Terzo</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>
```

It's essential to add `AutoPostback=true` for this to work

Comment: Thank Buddy for the help. I have used AutoPostback=true. Still It is not Working for me.